# In a ring $R$, if $x$ is not equal to $0$, then $x + x + x + x + x$ is never equal to $0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> In a ring $R$, if $x$ is not equal to $0$, then $x + x + x + x + x$ is never equal to $0$.

Can anyone tell me how to go about proving this.

Comment: But this is true for $x =1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

Answer (score 4):

This is not true: in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ (or any ring of characteristic $5$), $5x=0$ for all $x$.